# Does the sequence $x_n := n^2/\sqrt{n^6+1} + n^2/\sqrt{n^6+2} + . . . + n^2/\sqrt{n^6+n}$ converge? If it does, what value does it converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the sequence converge? If it does, to what value?
In my solution,

I have rewritten the expression as $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{1}{n^4}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{2}{n^4}}} + . . . + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{n}{n^4}}}$

since for any $i$ s.t. $1\le i\le n$, we can take $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{a_1}{n^3}}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{a_2}{n^3}}} + . . . + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+\frac{a_n}{n^3}}}$  s.t  $a_n = i/n \implies a_n \le 1$

now we can write $p = n^2$ and $q = \frac{1}{n^3}$


**Now, to find the limit can I apply partial limits as given below?**

$\lim_{p \to \infty} \lim_{q \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a_1y}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a_2y}} + . . . + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a_ny}}$

$\implies \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + . . . (n times)$

$ \implies \lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{x}} $

$ \implies \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}} = 1$

Comment: No, you can't.  Otherwise you get $1=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}n\stackrel{?}{=}\lim_{p\to\infty}\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{p}q=0$ and similarly $=\infty$.

Comment: Why not limit comparison test with the harmonic series?
https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcII/seriescomptest.aspx

Comment: Hint: Each summand in $x_n$ is smaller than $1/n$ and bigger than $1/(n+\frac1{2n^4})$ (prove that). Knowing this, what does that tell you about $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$?

Comment: @user10354138 can you explain why $\lim_{p \to \infty} \lim_{q \to \infty} \frac{p}{q}=0$. As this would be an indeterminant form and there's merit in expressing it as so. Would appreciate if you could give me another example why the partial limit is not allowed.

Comment: Because $\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{p}{q}=0$ for every $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing $n \in \mathbb N$, we see $$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^6+k}} \le \frac{n^2}{\sqrt {n^6}} = \frac 1n, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall k = 1,\ldots, n.$$ Thus $$x_n = \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^6 + k}} \le \sum^n_{k=1} \frac 1 n = 1.$$ On the other hand, $$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^6+k}} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt {n^6 + n^4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}, \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall k = 1,\ldots, n,$$ so $$x_n = \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^6 + k}} \ge \sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +1}} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1 {n^2}}}.$$ Thus $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}} \le x_n \le 1, \,\,\,\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$ The squeeze theorem then gives the limit.